# How to register for remote notifications in iOS 7 using Swift 2?

Tags: ios7, swift2, apple-push-notifications

How to register for remote notifications in iOS 7 using Swift 2?

I have tried this:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(
UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | 
UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound | 
UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert)
```

also this

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(.Alert | .Badge | .Sound)
```

But it's not working.

Comment: @EricD THanksss you saved my day . pls add as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift 2, these values are OptionSetType and you use them in an array like this:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotificationTypes([.Alert, .Badge, .Sound])
```